# Xpath Returns false

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

System Returns Validation Error :

**Sorry, test@y.com is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address.**

**Html Code of Error Message :**

```
<div class="error validate">
<h2 class="element-invisible">Error message</h2>
Sorry, <em class="placeholder">test@y.com</em> is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address.</div>
```

**I am trying Xpath :**

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[\n" +
            "    @class='errorvalidate' \n" +
            "    and contains(., 'Sorry,')\n" +
            "    and contains(., 'is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address.')\n" +
            "]")
```

I am trying to find system generated validation message dynamically for assertion but above xpath is unable to find message element.

Comment: sorry can you be more clear

Comment: What exactly do you want to find? If you just want to got the the Error message this Xapth would work fine-    `//h2[contains(text(),'')]`

Comment: I want correct xpath to find that message for assertion. My given xpath is not working.

Comment: does the class errorvalidate is valid? as the html shows 'error validate'

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam - Yes as far as I know space does not matter in xpath for class. By the way I tried with and without space in classname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reformatted your xpath, and also class name has its significance here,

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='error validate' and contains(., 'Sorry,') and contains(., 'is not recognized as a user name or an e-mail address.')]")
```

Comment: System is unable to find element using this xpath:(

Comment: @HelpingHands In that case, the problem might be somewhere else. The XPath should've worked to find the element you posted, see [demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/45505a718a40542e37fd5ecfeb1d259d)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I did mistake when placed xpath. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Hi please try like below

```
// now before getting error message 
// verify that class error validate exits 
// then only get error message 

List<WebElement> doesErrorClassExists = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='error validate']"));
WebElement myErrorClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='error validate']"));

if(doesErrorClassExists.size() > 0){
System.out.println("Error message is : " + myErrorClass.getText());
}
```